# PHP Form with File Upload & Other Information

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project where I'd like to have a submission form. The submission will include information to be filed in by the user as well as a file attachment. I've used PHP to make this work and I know everything is transferring to mysql database except for the actual attachment. For instance, I've attached a PDF and saw the name enter the database but not the size.

I attempted to base the code off of tutorials and questions I saw on this site. I'm concerned with the following code: $folder="uploads/"; which you can see integrated in my code below. Where will I find uploads/? Was there a particular folder I need to create to accept files? Where are the files actually saved if I am using phpmyadmin?

Thank you!

```
    <?php


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    

$name = $_POST['name'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$facebook = $_POST['facebook'];

$linkedin = $_POST['linkedin'];

$twitter = $_POST['twitter'];

$yourStory = $_POST['yourStory'];

$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];

$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

$folder="uploads/";

move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file);

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','cms');


$query = "INSERT INTO report(name, email, phone, facebook, linkedin,     twitter, yourstory, file, type, size)";
$query .= "VALUES  ('$name','$email','$phone','$facebook','$linkedin','$twitter','$yourStory','$file','$file_type','file_size')";

mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
?>
```

Comment: You are inserting 'file_size', not '$file_size'.

Comment: @PrzemysławJanWróbel Nice catch. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create that folder before use form for upload file and set access for write in that directory (write permission to webserver)

that folder path will be side of your php file ...

when you see your table in phpmyadmin you just see file path ..

Comment: any advice for how to do this. I've played around with the code but have had no luck!

Comment: create folder manually (not with code) and add write access to that.